# Read a local file

Tags: javascript

Is there no way for javascript hosted on a webserver to read a file on a client's local machine? (this has obvious security risks). I guess I'm wondering if there's any access granting a user can do, like drag and dropping a file into the browser, or explicitly selecting a file from a popup to get around this?

I know flash 10 allows reading of a local file, just wondering if there were any method to do this in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*... or explicitly selecting a file from a popup to get around this ...*

You could of course just upload the file to your server then...

Answer (score 2):

Who on their right mind would release a browser that let JS to... oh wait, you can with activeX, but only works with IE.

Comment: More specifically, it's the Scripting.FileSystemObject ActiveX Object that lets you do this.

Answer (score 2):

There is new File API being a working draft in W3C, and it is already implemented in Firefox 3.6, see

http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/FileAPI/
http://ajaxian.com/archives/w3c-publish-first-working-draft-of-file-api
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/12/w3c-fileapi-in-firefox-3-6/

Answer (score 1):

**[Nope, that's not possible...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript)**

However, see this:

http://www.mozilla.org/js/js-file-object.html