# javascript - not in the browser - but to process a file

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, serverside-javascript

I have written some javascript which reads data in a textarea (inside a browser)
and outputs the result in a string (as innerHTML) in a div.

It's brilliant and it does its job.

I would like to port it out of the browser.

I would like to reuse the same javascript (which effectively is just a function that given a string returns another string) out of the browser.

Ideally I would like to run it a commandline tool and say read file c:\input.txt and writes the response on c:\output.txt

Can somebody suggest how best I can achieve this ?

I looked around and came across to commonjs.org (which is very interesting) and node.js 
(which is interesting too) as well as other obscure projects.

Yet, I still don't know how to do this. If somebody has done something similar I would like to hear.

Many Thanks,

p.s.
I tagged this question 'server-side javascript' mainly to say that it's not a browser question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://RingoJs.org

It's a thin wrapper on top of Rhino. Makes dealing with files, modules, etc a lot easier, see for example: http://ringojs.org/api/master/fs/

Answer (score 1):

[Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) from Mozilla is javascript interpreter written in java which might do what you need.

Comment: Agree, Rhino is the best way to do this. You can crank out a commandline utility in no time. Also useful thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Comment: Rhino is good. Okay !!! 
But before I give the 'ok' I would like to hear from others. Ideally I would like to run some proper javascript engine (such as V8) rather than a javascript engine written in java.

Comment: v8 is written in C and rhino in java, i don't see how one is more 'proper' then the other?

Answer (score 1):

If your're on a windows system, you could the native c-/wscript interpreter using the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read and write files. Otherwise [jsdb](http://www.jsdb.org/) may be an option, where you can use the `Stream`-object.