# How could I read file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm using chrome now and I decide to convey a test about how to use javascript reading local file. Someone says it's easy but he uses IE, maybe on the chrome side things got a little diffrent, can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read and write into file using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Also, I realize that HTML 5 proposes new filesystem APIs. However, new solutions to this question should be put in a single place, like the duplicate I linked to, instead of spread out between multiple questions.

Comment: Thank you, but could you tell me more about the html5 filesystem APIs?

Comment: Thank you, it will be helpful:)

Answer (score 1):

Security considerations dictate that you don't have any access to the local filesystem through Javascript. You'd have to have your user upload the file to the server first.

Comment: That's not entirely true anymore, browsers that support HTML5 have an API that gives you access to local files via file-type input elements: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. This is an expansion of the original "no local files at all" sandbox, but the user still needs to manually specify the files.

Comment: @nwellcome it is supported only on some browsers. I think people has put lot of burden over HTML5. I'll be happy if every browser implements that before I die :)

Comment: @nwellcome is it not also the case that the browser only has access to files that have been created by the domain requesting them - same principles as cookie availability?

Comment: @PeterNixey The File API is read-only, the only way the spec mentions to get a reference to a file is via an input element's `FileList`, but I believe that file can be any file the underlying OS allows the browser to read. http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: @nwellcome - you're right, my apologies. I guess that if you have to access the file via a browser chromed viewer it's really not that different from uploading one to the web. Thanks for the tip