# How to load a client side file and load it in some table

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, loading

**The goal**

I want to load a client side file and put it a html table. The user will play with the data and try to save it later.

I know for security reason JS cannot load a local file. In this case, it's the user that tries to load the file makes the whole security thing look pretty stupid to me.

Is there any "clean" way to load a file ?

**Enviroment**

I am using ASP. The website will be used only inside the company, so it is a controlled environment. I know there's many JQuery plugin to load files to the server but in this case it's just to load in a table.

I know I could load the file to the server and refresh the page, but thats far from clean.

Any insight on this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Read a Local File INTO a webpage via Javascript or Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891385/how-do-i-read-a-local-file-into-a-webpage-via-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

how is that far from clean? it's probably 95% standard way of doing things. I think your "clean" definition needs to be cleaned.

I think you are in luck though with html5 because you have some additional controls at your disposal and the javascript may allow you to do that...check out the filereader api...also you could do the upload via ajax in html5 as well.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=uVNLLJ1oOOb