# Fetching and saving user IDs to individual guilds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Basically what I want to do is to read a json file and firstly fetch a guild's ID from it and then search for a user's ID in this guild.

Let's say this is the sample of json file:

```
{Guilds ID}:
    {Users ID}:
        Value: "Yes"
        Value2: "No"
    {Users ID}:
        Value: "Yes"
        Value2: "No"
{Guilds ID}:
    {Users ID}:
        Value: "Yes"
        Value2: "No"
    {Users ID}:
        Value: "Yes"
        Value2: "No"
```

I tried using:

```
Variable[message.guild.id] = {
    User: "User ID"
    }
```

but this won't really work as I can't get variables only to specific user's ID like this. I probably made it complicated but can someone please help? I also want to save the file. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of "let's say" it is better to give the actual JSON in the example. Your example is not valid JSON format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
var data = {
  "guild1": {
    "userId1": {
      "Value": "Yes",
      "Value2": "No"
    },
    "userId2": {
      "Value": "Yes",
      "Value2": "No"
    }
  },
  "guild2": {
    "userId3": {
      "Value": "Yes",
      "Value2": "No"
    }
  }
}

if (data["guild1"].hasOwnProperty("userId2")) {
  console.log("Value for userId2 in guild1: " + data["guild1"]["userId2"].Value);
}

if (!data["guild1"].hasOwnProperty("userId5")) {
  data["guild1"]["userId5"] = {
    "Value": "Yes",
    "Value2": "No"
  }
}
console.log("Added new user userId5 to guild1")
```

If your JSON data structure consists of nested objects, where guild objects contain user objects, you can check if an user belongs to a guild by using the `hasOwnProperty()`method as shown in the example above. Note, you shall not use `data["guild1"]["userId<x>"]` instead as this would add a property `"userId<x>": undefined` if it does not exist in the given guild! See also [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WittigMarcus/kcgv8d6b/).

EDIT: As you also asked how to add an user to a guild I have extended my example. Regarding reading and writing JSON have a look here: [reading and writing json file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259590/reading-and-writing-json-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it tomorrow and I would try and geet it to work. If something would go wrong I'll ask you if you don't mind.

Comment: Okay, sorry for not responding for so long but I was quite busy. Anyways, thanks for your answer it worked! :D Thanks for this again. One note though, I prefer checking if certain property exists just by doing "if (!data["guild1"]["userID"]) {Do something}. I think it's much easier and clearer to see.