# Native d3.js methods to save / store / write data to a database?

Tags: database, d3.js, save, store

I would like to store freely formatted (JSON, XML, CSV) d3 data sets back to a database, preferably using (for the sake of consistency) **native** d3 methods.

Is this already catered for in d3, and if not, can existing d3.js methods be coaxed into handling this?

Examples would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something that you can do with Javascript -- there's no direct access to things like databases. This is not a restriction of d3, but Javascript itself. What you can do is post data to a server which will then add it to a database. There's no support in d3 for that though, only for retrieving data.

There are plenty of other Javascript libraries though that allow you to post data to a server, for example [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Ok, granted, perhaps I overshot the mark by referring to databases. Let's make it simpler. If this is code to read from a local file:  

    d3.json(
     "http://localhost:8000/data.json"
     callback_function
    )  

￼
...how would I **write** to the same file. :-)

Comment: Same thing. You can't really. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript) for some more information.