# Saving data obtained from a URL to disk using Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, file

I have searched google forever and all I find is different ways to save files to local disc - most of them of "Intermediate" or "advanced" level.

My problem is, I'm trying to write a javascript function to save, say, data from the link `http://localhost/Georg/api/stopareas/single/1035` in either Excel or XML format on the local disc. All the examples I have tried to use did not really help much.

Need some pointers on how to do this using JS.

Comment: You've tagged this JavaScript and .net … are you asking about JS running under WSH?

Comment: No, its runned in asp the javascripts(normal index site).

Comment: So you want to use JavaScript, running in a web browser to save to a file on the user's hard disk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read and write into file using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript)

Comment: I will take a look at that post, hopefully it gives me more hints. And no it isnt same user, just havent had time change my nickname :)