# Create file from file raw data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, blob, jszip

How to write image raw content response from php to file with Javascript?

Actually I am using [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to compress some files in chrome extension. I am accessing the files with a rest call which gives response as file raw content(response as php file_get_content())

Comment: you can't, or at least not directly, but there are ways around this; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

No you can't!

javaScript himself can't for security reasons...

- You can use Ajax to send requests to a php function that will return you the file content
  or
- You can use [TiddlySaver jquery plug in](http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html) which uses an applet (Note that the TiddlySaver applet is required on Opera and WebKit-based browsers (Safari, Chrome). The applet has to be present in the same folder as the respective HTML document. )