# how to insert content of text file into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, output

I have a text file containing a series of questions with multiple choices, and I would like to insert them in a multidimensional array. The questions at `array[0][0]` and multiple choices in `array[0][1]`, `array[0][2]`.... and so on. But I don't know how to open the file and then proceed to insert into array in javascript
text file format

```
what is 2 + 2?
2
4
6
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Comment: @WeeYou No. the question asked is something different than the link you have provided....

Comment: You can't read files in Javascript.