# How to save progress in an html game

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to know how I can save the progress a player has made in a game that I am making. Could I do this through cookies or how else can I save to the players computer? Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Comment: localStorage will do it

Comment: Cookies is probably your best option if you're wanting it to work on all browsers but you do have to remember that anything saved on the client side has the possibility of being deleted either by the user or and antivirus or an optimization program so you can use it just don't make your page depend on it in order to function. Local storage is full of permissions and is constantly changing and the plug ins like Java that can use it easier are losing support rapidly.

Comment: The one way you could use local storage would be to create a downloadable file that the user can save then have them load it through an input when they want to resume their saved game.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have pretty much two options for saving localy using Javascript, which are **cookies** and **localStorage**.

### With Cookies:

The `document.cookie` property is used for setting, reading, altering and deleting browser cookies.

- To set a cookie, `document.cookie="cookiename=Foo Bar";`, alternatively like so if you want an expiry date: `document.cookie="cookiename=Foo Bar; expires=Mon, 18 Jan 2016 12:00:00 UTC";`
- To read a cookie, just the code `document.cookie` will return all of your site's cookies on that page. It doesn't put them in an array, but instead a single string in the format of `cookiename=foobar; nextcookiename=foobar;`, etc. You can turn this into an array easily using `document.cookie.split("; ");`
- To alter a cookie, simply set it again as described above, as that will overwrite it
- To delete a cookie, set it again with an expiry date in the past. This will overwrite it, and then it will expire, deleting it.

### With localStorage:

The new HTML5 `localStorage` Object is another way to store data locally:

- To set an item in localStorage, use `localStorage.setItem('itemname','contents');`
- To read an item, it's `localStorage.getItem('itemname');`. You can check if an item exists using "truthy" values (i.e. `if(localStorage.getItem('itemname'))`)
- You can alter a localStorage item using `localStorage.setItem` as described above.
- You can delete a localStorage item using `localStorage.removeItem('itemname')`.

### Which should I use?

Cookies are supported in just about any browser that you can think of, however they expire (they get deleted after a set amount of time) and also can be disabled by users. Personally, I also find `document.cookie` a clunky interface.

localStorage on the other hand cannot be easily disabled by the user, and provides a more accessible interface for the programmer. As far as I'm aware, there is no expiration for localStorage. Since localStorage is new with HTML5, it may not work in some older browsers (however it's got great coverage on new browsers, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage). Note that there is [a limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values/) for storing data on **your entire site**, not just for one item.

In the end, it's up to you. Pick the one you think is going to work best for your game - if you're already using other HTML5 content (such as `<canvas>`) then there's no harm in localStorage and you'll be using a more reliable storage method. However, if you're happy with cookies then they are a perfectly viable option used by thousands of extremely popular sites - some even use both! One advantage to cookies is that they can be accessed by your web server, whereas localStorage cannot be.

Either way, you'll need to check out the [cookie law](https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/), which effects all types of storage on the user's computers by a web app.

Answer (score 6):

The hardest part of this problem is not finding a way to persist the data, but instead designing your game in such a way that you have a "game state" that can be serialized for saving between sessions.

Imagine you are writing a game with a player and a score and you're using two variables to represent them.

```
var player = { x: 4, y: 3 };
var score = 10;
```

It's relatively easy to save these variables with localStorage.

```
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem('player', JSON.stringify(player));
  localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(score));
}

function load() {
  player = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('player'));
  score = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('score'));
}
```

We have to remember to convert them to JSON before storing, because localStorage can only accept string values.

Each time you make your game state more complex you have to come back and edit both of these functions. It also has the undesirable effect of forcing the game state to be represented with global variables.

The alternative is to represent the entire state with one atom — in this case a Javascript object.

```
var state = {
  player: { x: 4, y: 3 },
  score: 10
};
```

Now you can write much more intuitive save and load functions.

```
var SAVE_KEY = 'save';

function save(state) {
  localStorage.setItem(SAVE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state));
}

function load() {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(SAVE_KEY));
}
```

This pattern allows you to keep state as a local variable and use these functions to work with it.

```
var state = load();
state.score += 10;
save(state);
```

In actuality it's quite easy to switch between storage mechanisms, but [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is probably the easiest to get started with.

For a small game you'll probably never reach the 5MB size limit and if you do, then you'll also find that the synchronous `JSON.stringify` and `localStorage.setItem` operations are causing your game to freeze for a few seconds whenever you save.

If this becomes a problem, then you should probably look for a more efficient way to structure your state and maybe consider designing an incremental saving technique, targeting [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) rather than localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your looking for.
Cookies are a great way to store data but can be edited by the client and some browsers have cookies turned of.

Web storage has its goods and bads too. If your game has to write masses of data and has lots of players it will quickly use up your bandwidth and may also take time to transfer depending on the clients connection. The upside is that it is fully controllable by you. Once the data has been sent, it can not be edited by the client.

Javascript has some great file I/O utils to help you on the way. Here is a great tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O

If you decide to go with cookies it can be harder or easier depending on your skill. Again, here is a great tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.

Hope this helps!!!

Edit---
When I mentioned client I was really meaning to say player :D