# Simple way to store data(e.g. scores)

Tags: javascript, store

I wrote a game (will be played on a server) and I want to store the high scores from the players. The stored scores should be available and accessible all the time for all the players.

What would a good approach towards this (I would prefer vanilla.js) is possible?

Comment: You tagged it under [javascript] which makes this question, too brad, primarily opinion-based and unclear!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save progress in an html game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847231/how-to-save-progress-in-an-html-game)

Comment: @KeeganKuhn I would say it is a bit different because he is asking how to store the results for all players of the game to see, so I'm assuming its a multi-client game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you will need a server or a service to do this. Since creating your own server requires an actual machine and a lot of work and maintenance, a service might better suit your needs.

The best service I have found, that is free with limited bandwidth, is [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). It is a database as a service, and you can use it to store things just like you would locally in a local or session storage. If your game becomes huge and uses a lot of bandwidth, you'll need to start paying, but maintaining a server is not free either.

Answer (score 1):

If the scores only need to be accessed during the current session, use variables. For example:

```
score = 0;
if ( pointEarned ) {
    score++;
}
alert(score);
```

If you need to access the variable after the session, [Toastrackenigma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2691058/toastrackenigma) has a great explanation at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34847231/how-to-save-progress-in-an-html-game).

Comment: No. I want to store and access it after the game session.

Comment: See the link if you need to use the data after the session.