# java script can not automatically write to hard disk But Java can do so

Tags: javascript, java

I was just reading one of the JavaScript resource and found following statement written.

> javascript can not automatically write to hard disk But Java can do so.

Can somebody please elaborate?

Comment: javascript `!=` java

Comment: why you are comparing apple and chair?

Comment: You can also check this question, if you are interested in writing to files inside javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Javascript is a scripting language that lives inside the browser. As such it is bound and restricted by the browser.

Java on the other hand is being executed as a stand alone application. Having all the rights of the person currently logged in. This means that if the logged in user has rights to write to the hard drive so does the java program.

Luckily javascript does not get those rights from the browser. The major reason for this is security. You do not want a virus written to your hard drive while just browsing a website.

And indeed Javascript is by no means Java, it is not even close to it.

Comment: *"Javascript is a scripting language that lives inside the browser"* - careful, we're in the 21st century now. Javascript is a general purpose language used for many solutions, including on the server (Node.js), in the NoSQL database (MongoDB) and even inside the Java Virtual Machine (Nashorn).

Comment: @Gimby good point. I was speaking of the traditional way to use javascript. When running on servers etc it also becomes possible to write to disk.

Comment: Indeedy. And that same sandbox would pretty much also apply to Java when run as a plugin within the browser, although there you have some freedom to open it up through the client granting access. In javascript land you can only go as far as the local storage API.