# Writing local files using javascript or other technology

Tags: javascript, web, text

I have seen lots of posting about people wanting to write text files using Javascript.  It looks like this used to be possible.  I have tried lots and lots of the examples, but can't get any to work short of Downloadify.

I am looking for something that will let me write a text value out to a local file on my own machine.  I am running the Javascript locally and not on a web server. I would like this to be written out immediately and not require pressing a Download button like Downloadify.

Are there any options?

Comment: this question has been asked several times, you might find some useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012580/is-it-possible-to-write-data-to-file-using-only-javascript and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

you can actually use html5 local storage

```
localStorage.setItem(KEY, VALUE);
```

to set the key/value pair(s) and

```
var result = localStorage.getItem(KEY);
```

to get the value of the key

The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date.

Comment: Thanks.  Does localStorage object create file? Which one do I set for the file name?

Comment: I tried using:
     function SaveDatFileBro(localstorage) {
  localstorage.root.getFile("info.txt", {create: true});
}
but this did not seem to work.

Comment: @Rob `localStorage` is internal to the browser. It uses files to save the data between browser executions, but the filename is chosen by the browser, it's not something the application can control.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried
    localStorage.setItem("Rob", "this_is_it");
I would have thought it would have written the value "this_is_it" out to a file.  I did a PowerGrep for "this_is_it" but nothing came back.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work and write out a file using the following function:

```
function write_it(win){

var textToWrite = win;
var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
var fileNameToSaveAs = "win.txt"

var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";

downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
downloadLink.click();
```

}