# Write to a local file using angular2 typescript locally

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

How to write to an external file using typescript in angular2 (client side) ? I need to write some text into a file in some format. Can anyone help? I googled and saw only how to do using node library or javascript blob. Is there a typescript way of doing it?

Comment: you can't able to write to external files

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to local files. The code runs in the browser and the browser will prevent access to the local file system. What you can do is to create a download link with a data url, that the user clicks and saves to a file.

See also [How to read and write into file using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript) for a limited way to writ to local files.

Comment: That's how it is done in JS, it is the same way is it?

Comment: TypeScript will be compiled to JS, therefore in the end it's the same.