# How to save image in local folder using Angular2?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to stack overflow as well as in angular2. i am currently learning how to upload image in local folder inside application using angular2. i can't understand how to save images in local folder. i have read many answers from stack overflow but all of them (almost) using angularjs not angular2. can any one please help me how to upload and save images in local folder using angular2 and nodejs. i have just html code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="single">single</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="single"  
 /></div>
```

i have spent my whole night but all in vain. can someone please give me simple tutorial by just showing how to save in local folder using angular 2

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547945/write-to-a-local-file-using-angular2-typescript-locally

Comment: I am done with it. Using django for backend.

Answer (score 3):

I created this very detailed example working with an **Item** model, component, service, route and controller to select, upload and store a picture using latest versions of Angular and NodeJS (currently Angular 6 and NodeJS 8.11) but should work in previous versions too.

I'm not going to explain much taking in consideration you can learn and understand most of it just by examining the code. But do not hesitate to ask if you don't understand something on your own. Here we go...

**item.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { mimeType } from './mime-type.validator';

import { ItemService} from '../item.service';

import { Item } from '../item.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  item: Item;

  form: FormGroup;

  imagePreview: string;
  private id: string;

  loading = false;

  constructor(public itemService: ItemService, public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  initForm() {
    this.imagePreview = item.imagePath;

    const item = this.item ? this.item : new Item();

    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl({value: item.id, disabled: true}),
      name: new FormControl(item.name, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)] }),
      image: new FormControl(item.imagePath, { validators: [Validators.required], asyncValidators: [mimeType] })
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.initForm();

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap: ParamMap) => {
      if (paramMap.has('id')) {
        this.id = paramMap.get('id');
        this.loading = true;

        this.itemService.getItem(this.id).subscribe(data => {
          this.item = new Item(
             data._id,
             data.name ? data.name : '',
             data.imagePath ? data.imagePath : '',
          );

          this.form = this.initForm();

          this.loading = false;
        });
      } else {
        this.id = null;
        this.item = this.form.value;
      }
    });
  }

  onImagePicked(event: Event) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.form.patchValue({ image: file });
    this.form.get('image').updateValueAndValidity();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      this.imagePreview = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

  onSave() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    this.loading = true;
    if (!this.id) { // creating item...
      const item: Item = {
        id: null,
        name: this.form.value.name,
        imagePath: null
      };
      this.itemService.createItem(item, this.form.value.image);

    } else {  // updating item...
      const item: Item = {
        id: this.id,
        name: this.form.value.name,
        imagePath: null
      };
      this.itemService.updateItem(item, this.form.value.image);
    }

    this.form.reset();
  }

}
```

The mimeType is a validator to limit the user selecting / loading only an image file from a group of image types...

**mimetype.validator**:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Observer, of } from 'rxjs';

export const mimeType = (control: AbstractControl): Promise<{[ key: string ]: any}> | Observable<{[ key: string ]: any}> => {
  if (typeof(control.value) === 'string') {
    return of(null);
  }
  const file = control.value as File;
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  const frObs = Observable.create((observer: Observer<{[ key: string ]: any}>) => {
    fileReader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      const arr = new Uint8Array(fileReader.result).subarray(0, 4);
      let header = '';
      let isValid = false;
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        header += arr[i].toString(16);
      }
      switch (header) {
        case '89504e47':
          isValid = true;
          break;
        case '89504e47':    // png
        case '47494638':    // gif
        case 'ffd8ffe0':    // JPEG IMAGE (Extensions: JFIF, JPE, JPEG, JPG)
        case 'ffd8ffe1':    // jpg: Digital camera JPG using Exchangeable Image File Format (EXIF)
        case 'ffd8ffe2':    // jpg: CANNON EOS JPEG FILE
        case 'ffd8ffe3':    // jpg: SAMSUNG D500 JPEG FILE
        case 'ffd8ffe8':    // jpg: Still Picture Interchange File Format (SPIFF)
          isValid = true;
          break;
        default:
          isValid = false;
          break;
      }
      if (isValid) {
        observer.next(null);
      } else {
        observer.next({ invalidMimeType: true });
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
  return frObs;
};
```

**item.component.html**:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSave()" *ngIf="!loading">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name" autofocus>
  <span class="error" *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid">Name is required.</span>

  <!-- IMAGE BLOCK -->
  <div class="image">
    <button class="pick-image" type="button" (click)="filePicker.click()">
      Pick Image
    </button>
    <input type="file" #filePicker (change)="onImagePicked($event)">
    
    <div class="image-preview" *ngIf="imagePreview !== '' && imagePreview && form.get('image').valid">
      <img [src]="imagePreview" [alt]="form.value.title">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="buttons-bar">
    <button class="submit" type="submit">SAVE</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Using some CSS to hide the input type "file" HTML Element because it looks ugly but still necessary to trigger the user browser to open a dialog window to select a file for upload (a nice button is shown instead for a better user experience)...

**item.component.css**

```css
.pick-image {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(150, 220, 255, 0.7);
  width: 100px;
}
.pick-image:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(150, 220, 255, 0.9);
}

input[type="file"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.image-preview {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.image-preview img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

**item.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Item } from './item.model';

const SERVER_URL = environment.API_URL + '/items/';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ItemService {
  private items: Item[] = [];
  private itemsUpdated = new Subject<{items: Item[], count: number}>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  getItems(perPage: number, currentPage: number) {
    const queryParams = `?ps=${perPage}&pg=${currentPage}`;

    this.http.get<{message: string, items: any, total: number}>(SERVER_URL + queryParams)
      .pipe(map((itemData) => {
        return {
          items: Item.extractAll(itemData.items),
          count: itemData.total
        };
      }))
      .subscribe((mappedData) => {
        if (mappedData !== undefined) {
          this.items = mappedData.items;
          this.itemsUpdated.next({
            items: [...this.items],
            count: mappedData.count
          });
        }
      }, error => {
        this.itemsUpdated.next({items: [], count: 0});
      });
  }

  getItemUpdatedListener() {
    return this.ItemsUpdated.asObservable();
  }

  getItem(id: string) {
     return this.http.get<{
        _id: string,
        name: string,
        imagePath: string
     }>(SERVER_URL + id);
  }

  createItem(itemToCreate: Item, image: File) {
    const itemData = new FormData();
    itemData.append('name', itemToCreate.name);
    itemData.append('image', image, itemToCreate.name);

    this.http.post<{ message: string, item: Item}>(SERVER_URL, itemData ).subscribe((response) => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }

  updateItem(itemToUpdate: Item, image: File | string) {
    let itemData: Item | FormData;
    if (typeof(image) === 'object') {
      itemData = new FormData();
      itemData.append('id', itemToUpdate.id);
      itemData.append('name', itemToUpdate.name);
      itemData.append('image', image, itemToUpdate.name);
    } else {
      itemData = {
        id: itemToUpdate.id,
        name: itemToUpdate.name,
        imagePath: image
      };
    }

    this.http.put(SERVER_URL + itemToUpdate.id, itemData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    );
  }

  deleteItem(itemId) {
    return this.http.delete<{ message: string }>(SERVER_URL + itemId);
  }

}
```

Now, in the backend (NodeJS using ExpressJS), picture you have your app.js where, among other things, you reference your connection with the database (here using MongoDB) and middlewares in the following order...

**app.js**:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemRoutes = require('./routes/items');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://username:' +
    process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW +
    '@cluster0-tmykc.mongodb.net/database-name', { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Mongoose is connected.');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Connection failed!');
  });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'angular')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});

app.use('/api/items', itemRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'angular', 'index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Your itemRoutes `items.js` file is in a `routes` folder...

**routes/items.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const extractFile = require('./../middleware/file');
const router = express.Router();

const ItemController = require('./../controllers/items');

router.get('', ItemController.get_all);

router.get('/:id', ItemController.get_one);

router.post('', extractFile, ItemController.create);

router.put('/:id', extractFile, ItemController.update);

router.delete('/:id', ItemController.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

Your ItemController `items.js` file in a `controllers` folder...

**controllers/items.js**

```
const Item = require('./../models/item');

// ...

exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');

  const item = req.body; // item = item to create

  const itemToCreate = new Item({
    name:         item.name,
    imagePath:    url + "/images/" + req.file.filename,
  });

  itemToCreate.save().then((newItem) => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Item created.',
      item: {
        ...newItem,
        id: newItem._id
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error while creating item: ', error);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Creating item failed!',
      error: error
    });
  });
};

// ...
```

And finally, the **`file.js`** middleware:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
  'image/png': 'png',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
  'image/jpg': 'jpg'
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    let error = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid mime type');
    cb(error, 'backend/images'); // USE THIS WHEN APP IS ON LOCALHOST
    // cb(error, 'images'); // USE THIS WHEN APP IS ON A SERVER
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const name = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');

    const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
    cb(null, name + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext);
  }
});

module.exports = multer({storage: storage}).single('image');
```

I simplified parts of an app of mine adapting to this example to make it easier to understand (and at same time leaving a lot in there to help completing the "circle"). I hope this helps.