# Possible to append lines of code to Javascript script in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, browserify

I have a `hello.js` (it's babelify transpiled react code) loaded with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/hello.js"></script>
```

and I want to append a few lines of code to the end of it. Is that possible?

Edit: The lines I want to add are:

```
var hello = _react["default"].createElement(Hello, {                             
  name: "World!!!"                                                                
});                                                                              

_reactDom["default"].render(hello, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Where `Hello`, `_react`, `_reactDom` are all objects created in `hello.js`. The lines themselves are arbitrary. My real question is can I add code to a prexisting script in the browser?

Comment: What kind of lines?

Comment: no clue what you want....

Comment: yes you can write the js file with some new lines of code at server side and then can reload the file again in browser.
check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript

Comment: So set up the build script to add lines of code to it?

Comment: No, you can't read the content of a script without performing another ajax request, you can't change the content of a script that has already ran, and you can't change it before it runs on the client. You can alter it client-side using your F12 devtools then reload the page with the altered script, but that will of course only work for you.

Comment: That doesn't sound so *Reactily*, you may want to read [thinking in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Comment: @k3llydev I'm in this situation because I want to pass props to a React component at the time a Jinja2 template is rendered. I don't know what those props' values will be until that moment, otherwise I would put the component's create/render lines in my original, not yet babelified code.

Comment: @thekthuser What if you handle everything in React after the template is done rendering?

Comment: @k3llydev Yeah, that's an option, but it requires quite a bit of code being re-written. I kinda feel like reactjs.org was lying when it said "you can use as little or as much React as you need."

Comment: @thekthuser did you imported correctly the respective [React CDN's](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html) needed for your project?

Comment: Why can't react pull that data out of the dom? or with fetch? or from the url? from cookies? from localstorage? there's all these other ways of passing data around.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). I suggest you post a new question that asks directly about the real problem you're having ("how to pass props to a React component at the time a Jinja2 template is rendered") instead of this assumed solution.

Answer (score -3):

Once you import a JavaScript file, you are able to use (and modify) its exposed variables, functions, etc.

If your `hello.js` has an exposed variable like:

```
let hello = 'Hello'
```

You would be able to modify it after the file is imported, for example:

```html
<script src='hello.js'></script>
<script>
  console.log(hello); // prints 'Hello'
  hello = 'HELLO'
  console.log(hello); // prints 'HELLO'
</script>
```

Comment: This would be perfect, but all I get is `ReferenceError: hello is not defined`, unless I make it a global variable with `window`.

Comment: The initial version of the questions did not include the whole context included later. In the example I wrote, of course, `hello` is in the global scope therefore it is accessible.