# Create HTML file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file

I'm looking for a way to use a JavaScript function to create a new HTML file in the local directory. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: this type of question has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/jquery-read-write-to-file/582281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Client Side) Yes, but you might need to create a new ActiveX Object, therefore the browser should be IE only.

(Server Side) Just use any server-side scripting language (JS is not one).

Comment: I am afraid there is server-side Javascript, for instance, Node.js :)

Comment: There's also Narwhal and RingoJS!

Answer (score 0):

Just for web sanity and security. Making JS do things like that is obtrusive. You might write a text file someone else might write virus.py on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

Using javascript to create html is generally a bad idea because that's not what javascript was designed for, and there is nothing about javascript that makes it well-suited for that task. You're much better off generating html with a server-side language like php, which is commonly used to create html.