# Reading in a text file in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-files

Im new to Jquery and Javascript and im wondering how can i read information from a text file stored on my server and write back to this file again afterwards? I couldn't find much information after googling the problem

I would also like to read in the data line by line and store it in an array, is this possible?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: You can read files from the server with AJAX, but you can't write to them with JavaScript only.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/jquery-read-write-to-file

Comment: Maybe you can use ajax and read your file with backend code. Then return the file data back to client. What backend you prefer to use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use some server side programming. If you want the data on the client, you can use javascript or jquery using some ajax solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file if server allows to get it via http but you cannot write to it

Read file can be done by simply `$().load(url)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RESTful API in order to achieve this. Use HTTP GET (jQuery/AJAX) to get the contents of a file, edit what you wish, and use a HTTP PUT (jQuery/AJAX) to write the changes back to the server.

Comment: In a RESTful API, shouldn't a PUT request be used to update the file contents?

Comment: Ahh yes that would work better, but you could technically also use POST. I will update my answer accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: POST would technically work just as good, its just a matter of conforming to the REST standards

Answer (score 0):

**Read information** - yes via ajax call. The javascript will get the text from the page - whatever it is html/php/asp and return it to the calling page.

**Read line by line** - it is possible if you write it yourself. There is no built-in function for this.  But then the text should be divided by lines.

**Write back** - JavaScript can`t do it by itself. You need an ajax and serverside.