# Extjs4 save file.json from treestore

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, treeview, extjs4

I have treepanel in my application. Data are loaded from a json file. I use the drag and drop plugin and I need to save the new organization in the JSON file. Do you know how ?

Comment: please provide an example JSON file, the model you are using for the tree and I can show you how to do this.  One thing that confuses me about your question is that...  do you want to submit the whole tree back to the server, or do you want the server to make the moves individually?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I think it is out of luck. Extjs is written in JS and JS is confined in browser only.

You can find more info in these links:
[Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery) or [How to read and write into file using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585234/how-to-read-and-write-into-file-using-javascript)