# Use Jquery to save into text file

Tags: jquery

Is there any method to use to save data from webpage to excel file or text file using jquery
?

Comment: no you cannot do that using jquery,  see following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no purely client-side solution using only a browser and jQuery, no. You either have to involve a web server (and even then, the user has to handle the "save file" dialog box), or a "thick" technology like Flash or a signed Java applet. (In either case, the user would have to grant the permissions to do it; most users being somewhat — and appropriately — paranoid, you'd have to already have a relationship with them.) Even the new [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), which offers limited access to the local file system (with the user's permission), doesn't support *writing* files.

You can open a window with the file data in it, but then the user has to take the action of saving it to disk.

Comment: I have got this page : http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html , is it ok to use it , i dont want to have heavy code , im not so good at coding ?

Comment: @rolandfeghaly: I'm not familiar with it, but note that it says it only works from local files (`file://` URIs). And it uses "thick" technologies (ActiveX, Java, etc.).