# Javascript to save files in browser?

Tags: javascript

I generate html pages which are viewed locally. Is there a way i can use javascript to save files in a user designated folder? (like C:/dev/myapp/here)

I looked at [HTML5 File API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications/) and see how to read files when a user selects them. No way to save files. I know how i can cache files by creating image tags but i like to generate a single button which will kick off a script to download a series of files (zip, gif, png, jpg). I dont suppose i can do that with javascript can i?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save text file on client machine using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717214/save-text-file-on-client-machine-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I dont suppose i can do that with javascript can i?

Nope, you cannot.