# Write to a file at a specific location on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a bit array from info gathered on my form, to be able to save and append it to a specific file on client side. I am able to prompt the user for them to save it, but I don't want to give them a choice of where to save the file. Is there anyway to force the save location, so all the user does it click a button and the file is appended to.

Answer (score 3):

You cant force location nor append to existing file client side.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it there are many security concerns about it. Please follow below link

[Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

For these purposes you can use Silverlight. Here is a link that will explain to you what is Silverlight: [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/what-is-silverlight/)

Silverlight is easy to integrate with you ASP.NET application, so you should try it out if installing plug-in at the client side is an option.

Here is a link that will help you do your task with Silverlight:

[Tutorial for opening and writing to files](http://geekswithblogs.net/PeterTweed/archive/2009/10/09/silverlight---opening-and-saving-files.aspx)