# Import to notepad using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notepad

Is there any link for exporting the datas to notepad?
I have some fields like
Name,
Age, and
WorkingStatus

These are text and textarea...

I want to insert this datas to the notepad.Is there any demos or code available?

Comment: possible diplicate of [Read/write to file using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Comment: if you just download the file as text/plain, you can then open it in notepad by clicking the completed download, but you can't force it to open per se. you can use http://danml.com/js/download if you need a download tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to have the browser open notepad, but you can use HTML5 features to save a file as text, and then open it on your own inside notepad.  Depending on the browser, you  may need to trigger saving the file on the user side.  Here's two references, which I'll summarize:

http://thiscouldbebetter.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/loading-editing-and-saving-a-text-file-in-html5-using-javascrip/

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Basically, you want to create and save a blob with your text.  It should look something like this:

```
var arrayOfStuff = [];
arrayOfStuff.push("Name            Age              Working status");
arrayOfStuff.push("-----------------------------------------------");
arrayOfStuff.push(document.getElementById("name").value);
// etc
var blob = new Blob(arrayOfStuff, {type:'text/plain'});

// (the rest is copied directly from the wordpress link)
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
if (window.webkitURL != null)
{
    // Chrome allows the link to be clicked programmatically.
    downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    downloadLink.click();
}
else
{
    // Firefox requires the user to actually click the link.
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
}
```

If notepad isn't a big deal, you should also be able to open this blob in an iframe as .txt, and then right-click and saveAs, if you prefer.

### Edit

Ok, this was actually new for me to play with, so some of my older information wasn't quite right.  Here's the javascript from the working fiddle:

```
var arrayOfStuff = [];
arrayOfStuff.push(document.getElementById("name").value + "\n");
arrayOfStuff.push(document.getElementById("email").value);
arrayOfStuff.push("\n");
arrayOfStuff.push(document.getElementById("phone").value);
arrayOfStuff.push("\n");
arrayOfStuff.push(document.getElementById("comments").value);
arrayOfStuff.push("\n");
alert(arrayOfStuff);

var blob = new Blob(arrayOfStuff, {type:'text/plain'});

var link = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
link.download = "details.txt";
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

The fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/xHH46/2/

There are a few lessons learned:

1. If you're on firefox, it gives you the option to open the .txt immediately in Notepad.  However, notepad isn't paying attention to the linefeeds, whether they're \n or \n\r, appended to the immediate string or added separately, so I'd recommend using Wordpad instead.  Or, you can save the file.
2. More importantly, realize that the link you display is based on whatever value is in the text when you create the blob.  If you don't have defaults, you'll get an empty file, because all the fields are empty.  The wordpress solution fixes this (and discusses using it within the past week), but the fix is ugly.  Basically, you'd have to click on a button, and the button would then make a link appear, and that link would give you the good file.

Comment: @Nithu I can't help you unless you want to mention what your doubt is.  :-P

Comment: @Nithu Sorry, got distracted by work.  The link is giving me a 404 - can't find the page.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein-sorry...I don't know what happend to that link..http://jsfiddle.net/xHH46/1/

Comment: @Nithu Updated with a working example.  Check out my new answer - to get it to work the way I expect you'll want, you may need to add a button that creates the link, and then click on that link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32380/discussion-between-nithu-and-scott-mermelstein)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with purely javascript. You need to generate the file server side and send it to the client.

Comment: in the realm of IE-only this is very possible, albeit not wise if you ask me.

Comment: you can generate files client-side in current versions of major browsers.

Comment: @rlemon Yes, that is true. But I believe the OP is looking for a cress-browser solution. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @dandavis I am not aware of this functionality. Thanks for the comment.