# how to make the remote file downloadable using javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Need to download the remote file into browser using javascript. I am having the url of the file. Download must happen in background

Comment: Download must happen in background -- you are trying to create backdoor when user visit your site?

Answer (score -1):

No, JavaScript doesn't have access to writing files as this would be a huge security risk.

see [Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

IF you want to simply download the content and use it in the script, 
using jQuery it's very simple:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "your/file/here",
    dataType: 'text',   // you can also use xml, json, html here
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("ERROR: "+textStatus+", "+errorThrown);
    },
    async: true
});
```

Comment: i done that using jquery. Now i need to make download without showing that to the user to the specified location

Comment: What do you mean with "to the specific location"? Writing to the file system? This won't work with JavaScript (see above).