# Ajax POST returns success, but doesn't update the JSON file

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to add data to *.JSON file, that has only this text: {}. Ajax returns "success", but the file remains as before. Also I have noticed if the JSON file is empty, nothing happens at all. Please, help me to find a solution. I don't get where the trouble is. Maybe, you know what else can be the reason of the problem. Thank you.

The code of the ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "data/test.json",
     data:  JSON.stringify({ "userName": "1", "password" : "1" }),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){alert("success");},
     fail: function(errMsg) {alert("fail");
     }
});
```

Comment: POST requests don't do that.  You need server-side code.

Comment: SLaks, thank you for the answer. But if the task contains no server-side code, what should i do to save data into the file?

Comment: I am sure you can't do filing on Client side, but some methods are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery

Comment: By the way you said that you don't have server side Ajax request is to either Server or an external Source (API, OTHER WEBSITE) Which acts as a Server Side.

Comment: @anna_manzhula can you tell what alert(data) returns you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution was to install denver and use PHP code on server-side.

This is code in the js file.

```
  deleteNewsItem: function(newsId, callback, scope) {
     var dataPath = this.dataPath;
      $.getJSON(dataPath + '/delete-news.php?id='+newsId, function(rawHeadlines) { 
         var headlines = [];
         $.each(rawHeadlines, function(index, rawHeadline) {
            headlines.push(rawHeadline.id);
        } 
     });
             if (callback) {
             callback.call(scope, headlines);
     }
     };
```

This is the code in the "delete_news.php" file.

```
<?php

$deleteId = isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:false;
   if ($deleteId){
     $content = file_get_contents('delete-news.json');
     $json = json_decode($content);

$newData = array();
foreach($json as $key=>$id){
$newData []= (array)$id;
}
$newData []= array("id"=>(int)$deleteId);


$fill_view = json_encode($newData);
file_put_contents('delete-news.json', ($fill_view));
echo $fill_view;
} else {
echo json_encode(array());
}
exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to save a json file with jquery alone.
You must implement a server side code in order to make that work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if the task contains no server-side code, what should i do to save data into the file? Or how can I find this code... I am sorry, I m very new to JS.

Answer (score -1):

You have some error in your code, first of all there is no such thing as failure, but error or fail . Try this and tell me if it helps.
I think there is no way to save data to the file using javascript/jquery (for security reasons) if you want to get or store information you need server side, if you are only trying to store small amount of data you can use cookies or localStorage("Key", "Value As Json");

You can save data into localStorage like this:

```
    $.get("data/test.json", null, function (data) {

    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

but unfortunately as i said earlier you can't save to the file using javascript/jquery, try to using localStorage for temporary storage.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Nothing has changed. The result is the same.

Comment: I think there is no way to save data to the file using javascript/jquery (for security reasons) if you want to get or store information you need server side, if you are only trying to store small amount of data you can use cookies or localStorage("Key", "Value As Json");

Comment: Yes, I am trying to save the numbers of deleted Items' Ids of the ItemList. The structure of the project assumes that I should store this data into JSON file.. or maybe I can get this file into the local storage?

Comment: localStorage saves data in string representation, i.e. you can save json in it but not the file.