# Reading files with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to read a file (server-side) using jQuery. I have tried code supplied by multiple sites and it has not worked.

The code I tried last is:

```
jQuery.get("users/" + get("user") + "/display.txt", function(data) {
    fullName = data;
});
```

However the variable 'fullName' (which is previously declared in the code) comes out as 'undefined'. How can I get this to work?

EDIT: Full code (excluding CSS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chat</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function get(variable) {
                var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var vars = query.split("&");
                for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                    if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
                }
                return(false);
            }
            var fullName;
            var file = "users/" + get("user") + "/display.txt";
            jQuery.get(file, function(data) {
                fullName = data;
            });
        </script
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#B2C2F0">
        <div class="window">
            <div class="rightCorner">
                <span><script type="text/javascript">document.write(fullName)</script></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the variable? It's an async call, so if its outside the callback, it won't work.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: What does "not work[ed]" mean?  Where are you trying to read `fullName`?  You're aware that this is AJAX and is therefore asynchronous, right?  That means the AJAX request runs in the background and the rest of your code continues.  `fullName` won't be set until the AJAX call is done at some point in the future.

Comment: if you debug the value of data in the same function scope, it have some value?, remember that ajax call are async

Comment: What if you try not using the shorthand get, and use $.ajax so you can tweak with the data type etc more easily.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read/write to file using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Comment: I'm very new to ajax and jQuery. When I say that I mean I literally started today. I do get an error in the console, it says that cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes.

Comment: You can only use AJAX when your files are on a (local or remote) web server.  Since you're just learning, you should learn the *correct* way.  Don't use `document.write` ever.  What you want to do is lose the `fullName` variable and in the callback for the AJAX call, use `$('.rightCorner')` and `.html(data)` to add the text to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify `fullName` var with `data` value inside that function and read it outside.
If you need to use that info outside the function, you need to *export* the `data` value within another function.

Something like:

```
var fullName = "not-set";
console.log('fullName is:', fullName); // not-set

function set_fullName( data ) {
    fullName = data;
    console.log('fullName is:', fullName); // must be `Levi` now
} 

jQuery.get("users/" + get("user") + "/display.txt", function(data) {
    set_fullName(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just trying to access fullname before the ajax call finishes.

Try this:

```
var fullName = "";
function getUserName(username){
    jQuery.get("users/" + get("user") + "/display.txt", onGetComplete);
}
function onGetComplete(data){
    fullName = data;
    continueProgram();
}
function continueProgram(){
    console.log(fullName);
}

getUserName();
```