# open a .txt file using jquery only and then add a Line and Save . I am doing this to make an application using only jquery and no server side language

Tags: jquery

I want to open a **.txt file** on my maching using only **jquery** and then apppend a line to the **END OF FILE**  and then save it.

Please tell me a solution . Or if it possible using jquery or not

Comment: Better and easier would be to use AJAX and then use file operations of any server side language like PHP etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read/write to file using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

> No, JavaScript doesn't have access to writing files as this would be a huge security risk to say the least. If you wanted to get/store information server-side, though, you can certainly make an Ajax call to a PHP/ASP/Python/etc. script that can then get/store the data in the server. If you meant store data on the client machine, this is impossible with JavaScript alone. I suspect Flash/Java may be able to, but I am not sure.
>
> If you are only trying to store a small amount of information for an unreliable period of time regarding a specific user, I think you want cookies. I am not sure from your question what you are trying to accomplish, though.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Comment: If the question has been already answered on SO, instead of copy/paste you should mark it as "duplicate".

Comment: i want to make an application using only jquery . which will not use database but would use a .txt file on which it will CRUD . The enitre app is to only use jquery and Html 5