# How do I update JSON data in a file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I first get a JSON array using this JavaScript code:

```js
$.getJSON("myJSONfile.json")
    .done(function(data) {
      myData = data;
    });
```

myData is a global variable.

I then add information to myData. How do then update the myJSONfile.json to contain the new data.

Sorry if that was confusing.
Josh

Comment: What is the question / problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: i do not know how to send the data from my javascript file into my JSON file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/write to file using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can not write to any file using `JavaScript` alone. Just cookies or local (or session) storage. You can write `JSON` into local storage and just use `JSON.stringify` to serialize a `JavaScript` object.

```
localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(myData));
```

And to retrieve the object

```
var myData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
```

If you really want to write something in the file, you need use the server script like `php` or `asp`. Send `myData` to the `php`, and `php` will write what you want.

```
<?php
$myData = $_GET['myData']

$fp = fopen('myJSONfile.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($myData));
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

// step 1: send data to the server

```
$.post("handler.php", {data: myData}).done(function(){
    //do something after upload
})
```

// step 2: write it to the file using PHP

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['data'];

/* sanity check */
if (json_decode($json) != null)
{
   $file = fopen('myData.json','w+');
   fwrite($file, $json);
   fclose($file);
}
else
{
  // user has posted invalid JSON, handle the error 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The data received should now be in the myData variable. I would recommend putting a debugger; statement in your code so that you can have a look at the data you have received.

```
$.getJSON("myJSONfile.json")
.done(function(data) {
  myData = data;
  debugger;
});
```

If you open up developer tools in chrome and select sources, the next time you run your code, it will pause on the debugger; and allow you to enter myData into the console and peer into the object.

Once you know this you should be able to set myData.aProperty = 'newValue'