# How to save the parsed anchor elements in local file with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

To open `https://www.yahoo.com/` in chrome ,and to click `input`--`console`

```
var as=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
     console.log(as[i]);
 }
```

Now all the 132 anchor elements showed in chrome's console,how to save the parsed anchor elements  in local file with js ?

Comment: Due to browser restrictions I don't believe you can write to disk from the browser.  Someone may correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe your best bet would be to create some type of link that allows a user to download the data.

Comment: It's not possible to save the file in your server, directly from JavaScript, since that would cause **massive security problems**. You will have to **use a server-side language** for that or you can use **`Blob`** and when you're done provide a download link.

Comment: use `blob` then append the every thing on `blob` .finally download it.

Comment: Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery