# Writing on file using jQuery .post method

Tags: jquery, html

I've managed to read from a file on my computer using the `$.get()` method. I know that Chrome doesn't allow reading from file but Firefox does. I was wondering, is there a way to write on a file using the `$.post()` method or any other method? 
Thank you very much!

EDIT:
I've arledy read that question and they say that you can't read from file, but I did that thanks to Firefox. So I wanted to ask another question to see if writing on a file is really impossible.

Here is my `$.get()` code:

```
$.get('words.italian.txt',function(txt){
    var ris=[];
    var lines = txt.split("\r\n");
    var j=0;
    for (var i = 0, len= lines.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(lines[i].length==parola.length){
            ris[j]=lines[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't made any attempt on writing with `$.post()` but i think that it's possible.

Comment: Would you mind the code which you tried so far for both $.get and $.post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)