# How to store a jquery generated file in a temporary location at cient machine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am generating an excel (`.xls`) file from HTML table data using a `Table2Excel.js` library and I need to store it at a temporary location, I need to then fetch this file using the temporary path name and send it as an email attachment.

If there is a workaround, it'll be most appreciated.

Edit: Sending an email isn't the focus of question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)