# How to fetch data in option tags in html from a `.txt` or `.css` file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, csv

I am having 22 dropdowns (`<select>` tags) with 300 options in each. Using jQuery, I am hiding some options everytime according to earlier selections of an user.

But the problem is, to process all the 6600 options, html page is taking few seconds after selecting every dropdown option.

Is there way to store the options in other .txt or .csv file and load from them? Or any other way to speed up?

Answer (score 1):

1.If your drop down list won't change frequently, you may consider store the 6600 options to JS variables. (Bypass the "fetch" process time)

2.If you need to fetch the option every time (the option might changes by time to time), I suggest that you load the 300 options when the drop down menu (`<select>` tags) is clicked, instead of loading 6600 options at once or at the very beginning.

3.Store the data and load them from .txt/.csv might take more times.

If you insist, you can find some references using JQuery to read/write a file:

Read/write to file using jQuery:
[Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Also, I recommend use server side language to handle files content.